# Powers of a half that sum to one

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Call every subunitary ratio with its denominator a power of 2 a perplex.

Number 1 can be written in many ways as a sum of perplexes.
[image]

Call every sum of perplexes a zeta.
Two zetas are distinct if and only if one of the zeta has as least one perplex that the other does not have. In the image shown above, the last two zetas are considered to be the same.

Find all the numbers of ways 1 can be written as a zeta with N perplexes. Because this number can be big, calculate it modulo 100003.

Please don't post the code, but rather the algorithm. Be as precise as you can.

This problem was given at a contest and the official solution, written in the Romanian language, has been uploaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulvp9of5b3bfgm0/1112_descr_P2_fractii2.docx?dl=0 , as a docx file. (you can use google translate)
I do not understand what the author of the solution meant to say there.

Comment: The parts that I can follow are that for a given N there is a representation of 1 that achieves the greatest denominator (the sum of the powers from 1/2 to (1/2)^(N-1), plus (1/2)^(N-1) again) and that, beginning from this representation, you can replace an instance of (1/2)^m with another representation of 1, by multiplying its denominators by 2^m, giving you a longer representation of 1. By counting unique ways that this can be done to representations shorter than N, I believe it comes up with ways to reach N.

Comment: For instance, one representation with N=5 begins by taking 1 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 and replacing 1/2 with 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8 (a reduction of the N=3 case by 1/2) to get 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8; another replaces both instances of 1/4 with 1/8 + 1/8 (a reduction of the N=2 case by (1/2)^2) to get 1/2 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8

Comment: I maybe missing the point but according to me the number of possibilities is infinite. You can increase the powers of half as much as you want. 1/4 can be replaced by two 1/8s, 1/8 can be replaced by two 1/16s....

Answer (score 0):

Well, this reminds me of BFS algorithms(Breadth first search), where you radiate out from a single point to find multiple solutions w/ different permutations.

Here you can use recursion, and set the base case as when N perplexes have been reached in that 1 call stack of the recursive function.

So you can say:

```
function(int N <-- perplexes, ArrayList<Double> currentNumbers, double dividedNum)
if N == 0, then you're done - enter the currentNumbers array into a hashtable
clone the currentNumbers ArrayList as cloneNumbers
remove dividedNum from cloneNumbers and add 2 dividedNum/2
iterate through index of cloneNumbers
    for every number x in cloneNumbers, call function(N--, cloneNumbers, x)
```

This is a rough, very inefficient but short way to do it. There's obviously a lot of ways you can prune the algorithm(reduce the amount of duplicates going into the hashtable, prevent cloning as much as possible, etc), but because this shows the absolute permutation of every number, and then enters that sequence into a hashtable, the hashtable will use its equals() comparison to see that the sequence already exists(such as your last 2 zetas), and reject the duplicate. That way, you'll be left with the answer you want.

The efficiency of the current algorithm: O(|E|^(N)), where |E| is the absolute number of numbers you can have inside of the array at the end of all insertions, and N is the number of insertions(or as you said, # of perplexes). Obviously this isn't the most optimal speed, but it does definitely work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering! Though I have problems understanding it... what is "N <-- perplexes" ? Could you rewrite this post using a more formal/basic language?(e.g. not use words such as "cloning")